# Regular expression only returns the first item when used in a Delphi application

Tags: regex, delphi

In an on-line RegEx tester this regular expression behaves as I expect, It matches on an Sentence starting with Xtal and when Declare MyDeclaration is entered. When I try and use it in my Delph application it only ever detects the first item, ie. Xtal.

This is my code

```
function GetItems(SourceCode: String; ItemCategory: TItemCategory): String;  Overload;
Var Regex: TRegEx;
    Match: TMatch;

    begin
      Match := DeclareRx.Match(SourceCode);
      while Match.Success do begin
        Result := Match.Groups.Item[1].Value;
        Match := Match.NextMatch;
      end;
    end;

    DeclareRx := TRegEx.Create('^\s*(Xtal)\s*=\s*[0-9]*+|^\s*Declare\s+([a-z]+[a-z0-9_])*\s+', [roIgnoreCase, roMultiline, roCompiled]);
```

I assume I am need to do something else in my Match code. Would appreciate an explanation of Match.Gorups.Item[]  Does the index refer to each RegEx term?

Comment: That's how regex works. You need to loop through the input text feeding the regex that part of the text that starts after the match you just found.

Comment: After installing RegExBuddy I have modified and tested my RegEx and it is working fine in the RegExBuddy but with the above code I am not getting the second item returned.

Comment: I only run  this RegEx on a single line and only expect Xtal or the Declare Capture groups to be returned.  I don't understand how looping through the text works. I thought my code above would return one or the other of the capture groups or if there is no match, nothing .

Comment: Once you've processed a match, strip off all the text up to and including that match, and then feed it into the regex. Repeat until no matches are found.

Comment: There will ever only be one match on the line, I am just never getting the match when I have a line starting with Declare.  I am having to use it in this way because I need to capture the line number where the match occured.  FYI, I am parsing program code text for an IDE I am developing.

Comment: You can't expect to parse code with regex. You need a parser.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an old Q and not sure why it has been revived.

The function you have shown does `MatchAgain` but overwrites the Result each time - probably not helpful.

I always use TPerlRegEx rather than TRegEx, but assuming they are the same:

`Groups.Item[0]` is the whole of the matching String, and then `Groups.Item[1]` is the first match group asked for, `Groups.Item[2]` is the second and so on.

You have a match group (brackets) around `Xtal` so this will always be your first match (which is what you are saying you get).

You probably don't want brackets around Xtal (it will always match without the brackets and there are no variations for the pattern so it's not clear to me why you would care).  So either remove the brackets around Xtal, or use `Groups.Item[2]` to get the actual match group you are interested in.

And if you want all matches, either add the matches to a TStrings, or concatenate the results, or provide a callback function to receive each match.